# «Расскажи(,) как дела»: нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Известно, что запятая не ставится в ряде устойчивых выражений (например, «питаться чем бог пошлет»). Можно ли, руководствуясь этим принципом, не ставить запятую в выражениях типа *расскажи как дела*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Расскажи, как (у тебя) дела.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным (местоимение пропущено).

Сравнить: **Рассказывай всё  как следует, не торопись.** *Как следует* - это значит *правильно, по порядку.*

Устойчивое выражение можно заменить  словом-синонимом, обычно это наречие в роли обстоятельства.

**Примеры** устойчивых выражения с союзом КАК:

И она убаюкивала себя, повторяя **неизвестно как** привязавшуюся к ней французскую поговорку

Всё делалось в спешке, мы не складывали дрова, а швыряли их с платформ **как попало**, громоздя кучами.

Лучше выбери часок, сядь и напиши всё **как следует**.

Comment: А почему "Ну как дела?" можно без запятой? (словарь Кузнецова). А можно и с запятой (там же).

Comment: Это простое предложение. Слово "ну" может быть частицей (нет запятой) или междометием (запятая ставится). Авторский вариант, зависит от наличия паузы.

Comment: Спасибо, я не подумал :)